# For a linear operator P, find P(g) with {e,f,g} an orthonormal basis

Tags: geometry

Let $\{e, f, g\}$ be an orthonormal basis. Let $P$ be a linear orthogonal operator acting in $E3$, such that it preserves the orientation of $E3$ and the following relations hold:
$P(e)=\cos\theta e +\sin\theta f$, $P(f)=\sin\theta e −\cos\theta f$.

1) Find $P(g)$.

We know that due to the Euler Theorem the linear operator $P$ considered above is $a$
rotation operator. 
2) Find the axis and the angle of this rotation. (Express answers in terms of $\theta$.)

For number 1) I got that $P(g) = -g$ as the determinant of said operator must be +ve as it preserves orientation, and then $P(g).P(e) = g.e =\theta$ and so on. Can anyone verify if this is correct?

For number 2) I have been got the angle of rotation to be $\pi$, however I am struggling to work out the axis of rotation. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number 1, you are correct.

For number 2, you could find the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue 1.

The most elementary, mechanistic way to do this is to write out the matrix for $P$ and solve $Px = x$ for a vector $x = (a,b,c)$. You will easily find $c = 0$ and
$${b\over a} = {\sin\theta\over 1 + \cos\theta} = {2\sin{\theta\over 2}\cos{\theta\over 2}\over 2\cos^2{\theta\over 2}} = \tan{\theta\over 2}\,.$$
Put $a=1$ and multiply through by $\cos{\theta\over 2}$ to find the axis of rotation as the line spanned by
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta\over 2} \\ \sin{\theta\over 2} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\,.$$
The rotation axis is in the $ef$ plane, and the operator maps $g$ to $-g$, so I think one can guess that the rotation angle is $\pi$. In general, the trace of a rotation matrix is $1+2\cos\phi$ where $\phi$ is the rotation angle. Here we find $1 + 2\cos\phi =-1$ so that $\cos\phi = -1$ as expected.